# excute order by statement by preparestatement not sort

Tags: java

I try to query a select sql with order by statement by preparestatement, It excuted, but when print, it 's not sorted. some one help me?

```
Connection conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnect();
        String sql = "SELECT  * FROM student ORDER BY ?";
        List<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement prepareStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            prepareStatement.setString(1, name);
            ResultSet rs = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setId();
                ......vv
                listStudent.add(student);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listStudent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a prepared statement you use `?` parameters or placeholders to pass actual values and not column names, like in a `WHERE` clause: `WHERE column1 = ?`.

So change to this:

```
String sql = "SELECT  * FROM student ORDER BY " + name;
```

and remove this line:

```
prepareStatement.setString(1, name);
```

Comment: Sorry for late to thank. Again, thanks so much for your help